Does the name of a service that consists of common nouns require a definite article?
Does the name of a service that consists of common nouns require a definite article?
For example, when a company offers a service named "Quick Data Recovery Service," and I need to refer to this specific service in normal sentences, is a definite article required ("the Quick Data Recovery Service") or not ("the Quick Data Recovery Service")?
I found some sentences on a webpage of T-Mobile and think that proper noun phrases without a proper noun (composed only of common nouns) may require a definite article, but I'm not sure at all.

If you buy both the Insurance Device Protection Plan and the Service Contract Device Protection Plan, you'll get a discount of up to $1.50 on the Insurance Device Protection Plan, depending on the device tier.

